# ScrollView not scrolling after setting View.OnTouchListener on it

Tags: android, scrollview, ontouchlistener

I have a scrollview that needs to be moved on top of another view and only after that start scrolling process. 
I've added a TouchListener on the ScrollView and implemented onTouch method - to be able to move the scrollview.
The problem is that event if the scrollview reaches the desired position - and the moving process is stopped - the scrolling does not take place.

I'm thinking maybe because I've attached the Touch listener - it somehow interferes with the scrolling listener or something?

Comment: try returning false in the onTouch and check if the scrolling works

Comment: Returning false now make the scrollview act weird - because the scroll  and touch events are enabled. When I tap the scrollview I see the scrollbar and the items seem to move a bit - but when the scrollview reaches the desired position - the scroll still doesn't work.

Comment: I need to disable the scroll until I reach the desired position and after that the scroll to be enabled.

Comment: shift the onTouch to the relative or the linear layout.. and let the scrollview have the onScroll listener.. else the scrollview will take the onTouch and it wont scroll.